# How can I get next week dates?

Tags: php

**Problem**

I'm using the below code to get the next week's date and second week's date. It works fine for first few records but later it starts giving year **1970**.

If the start date is **12/01/2013** it shows me coorect result that is:

Next week: **19/01/2013**

Second week: **26/01/2013**

but in another record where the date is **16/05/2013** it shows the below

Next week: **08/01/1970**

Second week: **15/01/1970**

Please guide me where I might be going wrong ?

**Code**

```
    //Date of when game started
    $starts_on = '12/01/2013';    

    //Next week's date from start date
    $next_week = strtotime(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($starts_on)) . "+1 week");
    $next_week = date('d/m/Y', $next_week);

    //Second week's date from start date
    $second_week = strtotime(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($starts_on)) . "+2 week");
    $second_week = date('d/m/Y', $second_week);

    echo $starts_on.", ".$next_week.", ".$second_week;
```

Comment: did you check if `$starts_on` contains the correct dates everytime it is retrieved?

Comment: yes it does! in the second record when the future dates are coming wrong in that the starts_on date is **16/05/2013**

Comment: I just want to add to the mystery: '13/05/2012' does not work but '12/05/2012' will. it seems if the date is greater than '12' we have an issue.

Comment: You're using `strtotime()` wrong.

Comment: PHP will interpret this as month/day/year, not day/month/year ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)).

Comment: Blame US ridiculous date format for that.  LSB, MSB, no let's try middle, least, most, that'll make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong format date. Check the note in the [`strtotime` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Check the documentation further:

> Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and [`DateTime::sub()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) in PHP 5.3 and later, or [`DateTime::modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) in PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use the DateTime Object, is better to manipulate dates (to add and substract dates from another is very easy with the object DateInterval)

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime("2013-01-12");
  //add one week to date
  echo $date->add(new DateInterval('P1W'))->format('Y-m-d');
  //add one week to date
  echo $date->add(new DateInterval('P1W'))->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Result:

```
2013-01-19
2013-01-26
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php

http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 0):

*Please try this*

```
$dt = new DateTime();
// create DateTime object with current time
$dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W')+1);
// set object to Monday on next week
$periods = new DatePeriod($dt, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6);
// get all 1day periods from Monday to +6 days

$days = iterator_to_array($periods);
// convert DatePeriod object to array
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($days);
```